# How do I publish multiple photos url to Facebook in the same post? (The photos are uploaded)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use this edge to publish multiple photos that I've already uploaded to the internet (I only know urls of those photos).

However the [api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/photos) require string Url but I have more than one Urls.
How do I upload those images(url) into the same post?

Note:

1. I'm trying to post those images to a page they should be able to upload without having any album.
2. It would be nice if you can give me the Url example of the solution

For example : POST /{page-id}/photos?message=foo&url=bar